# DB2 CLP Inline Comments

Tags: db2, comments, command-line-interface, db2-luw

We are seeing errors in the DB2 CLP with inline comments. Does anyone know what inline comment syntax is supported in the DB2 command-line processor?
We have looked at the [DB2 LUW 10.5 Comment Syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0056402.html) article, and we wrote something like this:

`SELECT * FROM sysibm.sysdummy1; --IGNORE-THIS`

It works in the tools we tried (e.g. IBM Data Studio) but our DBAs report that it fails in the DB2 CLP (`db2`).

This works:

```
create table testtab (column1 char(1), --IGNORE-THIS
 column2 char(1) )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

This does not:

```
grant select on table testtab to user someName;  --IGNORE-THIS 
db2 -tvf test.sql

DB21007E  End of file reached while reading the command.
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: you mean the DB2 CLP ?  I get the same symptom with DB2 V11.1.1.1 for LUW with the DB2 clp.

Comment: Yes, the command line processor (CLP) https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010409.html

Comment: The LUW docs state that the comment characters for the CLP -f option must be the first nonblank characters in the line. But the  CLP accepts inline comments for stored procedures and DDL, but not for all statements it seems.

Comment: It seems it is a feature of the CLP only, in other words the interactive CLI (db2cli) let me run SQLExecDirect() successfully if the statement has the terminator followed by an inline-comment. And the jdbc driver also accepts inline comments (as you found with DataStudio).   The doc link that specifies that for CLP -f option allows comments only when the first nonblank characters on the line are -- or /* is :  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html

Comment: @mao You have found the right article, but according to that article, the CLP should not accept *any* simple comments at the end of a line: "Comment characters must be the first non-blank characters on a line". Instead, as we have seen, it accepts some and not others. Still - I'll accept it as an answer if you enter it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is a feature (restriction) of the CLP only, and the CLP is inconsistent as you described. Might be worth a PMR. In other words the interactive CLI (db2cli) let me run SQLExecDirect() successfully if the statement has the terminator followed by an inline-comment. And the jdbc driver also accepts inline comments (as you found with Data Studio). The doc link that specifies that for CLP -f option allows comments only when the first nonblank characters on the line are -- or /* is : [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related, but `; --` was once upon the time introduced as a mean to be able to create triggers/function/procedures with `-tf` instead of -- say -- `-td@ -f`.

I vaguely remembered an old Usenet post where I asked about this, and after some searching I found it:
  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.databases.ibm-db2/goEiaG3jsAI/O9dOf4oISRUJ

It turned out that the post was from Feb 2004 :-)